# Jquery UI table - how to sort html table td cells

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-ui

Jquery ui - table :
I have a table like this :

```
<table>
  <tr>
      <td> 1 </td> 
      <td> 2 </td>
      <td> 3 </td>
  </tr>
 <tr>
      <td> 4 </td>
      <td> 5 </td>
      <td> 6 </td>
 </tr>
```

I want to sort it in such a way that , if i want to move the element "1" to "5" , then if I drag that element "1" and drop at element "5" , then they should exchange their places , then the table should be like this   :

```
   <table>
<tr>
  <td> 5 </td> 
  <td> 2 </td>
  <td> 3 </td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td> 4 </td>
  <td> 1 </td>
  <td> 6 </td>
</tr>
 </table>
```

Also, I have a handler image like image.jpg, with id : imageid inside each **td** that does the handling . I tried many times but i couldn;t get it to work

I have tried:

```
$("table").sortable({contentWith : 'table',handle : 'imageid' })  
$("table td").sortable({handle : 'imageid' })  
$("table tr").sortable({,handle : 'imageid' })  
$("table tbody").sortable({,handle : 'imageid' })  //for this,i added tbody in table ,but didnt work .
```

I am not saying that they didnt move at all, they are moving but not correctly .

some little code posted here so that you can edit fast     :
http://jsfiddle.net/Vq8CK/3/

Comment: If you create an example in jsFiddle (http://jsfiddle.net) it will make it a lot easier for people to help you.

Comment: link for small code in jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/Vq8CK/3/

Comment: I think i have a REALLY long horrible method...which will only be efficient for the use for the amount of cells you have in your example

Comment: ya, plz show me that...thanks

Comment: It's not done it'd be really long and messy i'm making one atm you can see my progess if you'de like......btw in the demo the number that come up are just that i know that it's functioning propperly  http://jsfiddle.net/Vq8CK/4/

Comment: thanks a lot for taking time to answer me

Comment: it's ok, i like jquery, i'll try hard to get you get a working demo :)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/11662/discussion-between-yusaf-and-ramesh-kumar)